# Devexpress XtraReport Exporting to PDF Arabic Letters appears on the host server separated

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, devexpress, export-to-pdf

I'm using xtraReport on my asp.net webform application and I made the functionality when I click the button I export the report to pdf file then show it with print dialog

when the application on my local machine it's working fine and the letters appear joined  but when I publish the application the arabic letters show separated.

Please Help

This is my code

```
private  void WriteDocumentToResponse(byte[] documentData, bool isInline, string fileName) {  

    string disposition = isInline ? "inline" : "attachment";  

    Response.Clear();  
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";  
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("{0}; filename={1}", disposition, fileName));  
    //Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;  
    //Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());  
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);  


    Response.BinaryWrite(documentData);  

    Response.End();  
}  


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  

    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString ["ID"],CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ;  

    if (id!=0 ) {  
        //Printing  
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())  
        {  
            using (var registrationPrint = new RegistrationPrint())  
            {  
                registrationPrint.Parameters["IDParam"].Value = id;  

                registrationPrint.DataSource = DbHelper.GetVisitor(id);  

                registrationPrint.CreateDocument();  
                var opts = new PdfExportOptions {ShowPrintDialogOnOpen = true};  

                registrationPrint.ExportToPdf(memoryStream, opts);  


            }  
              memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);  

            byte[] report = memoryStream.ToArray();  


            WriteDocumentToResponse(report, true, "Print");  
        }  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

I have to set full trust on my web.confg file